# slurmctld.service: Can't open PID file No such file or directory

Tags: slurm

I have the following error message after trying to start slurm on Ubuntu 18.04

`slurmctld.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory`

here's the ownership of the slurmllnl directory :

`drwxr-xr-x  2 slurm slurm   60 juin  22 11:06 slurm-llnl`

And in this directory i have slurmd.pid but i don't have slurmctld.pid

Here is my slurm.conf file :

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator easy.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=daoud
#ControlAddr=
#
#MailProg=/bin/mail
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
#SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
#SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm-llnl
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
#
#
# TIMERS
#KillWait=30
#MinJobAge=300
#SlurmctldTimeout=120
#SlurmdTimeout=300
#
#
# SCHEDULING
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
#SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/cons_res
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
ClusterName=cluster
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
#SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
#SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=daoud CPUs=64 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=16 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=standard Nodes=daoud Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a message issued by systemd, not Slurm, and is caused by using [PIDfile](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PIDFile=) in the systemd unit. Slurmctld should keep the Slurmctld from starting.

[Newer versions](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/commit/9249173482a8fe23d52b4f2fbf41482941fead77#diff-454fbaa46832a8eb4b39baaf234fd88299458ebb2346bad661ebb3f9eb1d5852) of Slurm switched to Type=simple, therefore not needing a PIDfile anymore

Comment: When i do `systemctl status slurmctld` i get  `Active: failed` . And if i try to run a slurm command like `sinfo` for example, i get `error: Unable to contact slurm controller (connect failure)` So i think slurmctld didn't start

Comment: But that's most likely not because of the message you posted. Check your slurmctld-logfile or try to start the slurmctld manually to see what happens and add any possible errors to your Post.